# powershell for parsing json and merging it into an xml file

Tags: json, xml, powershell, powershell-5.0

In powershell 5.0,  how to extract the "result" array of a dynamic `JsonToExtract.json` and uniquely-append the extracted values to be `<members>` beneath `<name>TargetName</name>` in an existing `file.XML`?  See below for the file structures and what Im trying to achieve.  Thanks in advance for the help!

**JsonToExtract.json**

```
  {
      "status": 0,
      "result": [
        "car",
        "bike",
        "wheel",
        "door",
        "fish",
        "mountains"
      ]
    }
```

**file.xml (before merging)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://*">
  <types>
    <name>Weather</name>
    <members>Cloudy</members>
  </types>
  <types>
    <name>TargetName</name>
    <members>car</members>
  </types>
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

**file.xml (Here is what i expect)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://*">
  <types>
    <name>Weather</name>
    <members>Cloudy</members>
  </types>
  <types>
    <name>TargetName</name>
    <members>car</members>
    <members>bike</members>
    <members>wheel</members>
    <members>door</members>
    <members>fish</members>
    <members>mountains</members>
  </types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
$file = [xml](Get-Content file.xml -Raw)
$json = Get-Content .\JsonToExtract.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$TargetNode = $file.Package.types | where { $_.name -eq 'TargetName' }
foreach ($j in $json.result)
{
        $e = $file.CreateElement(“members”,$file.Package.NamespaceURI)
        $e.set_InnerText($j)
        $TargetNode.AppendChild($e) > $null
}

$file.Save("$(Resolve-Path .)\fileOut.xml")
```